# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp\www\site1\includes\login.php on line 6

Tags: php

I know this is quite silly and i don't know what i am missing but i am getting this error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp\www\site1\includes\login.php on line 6**

for the below given code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login1']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['remember']))
    (
        setcookie("batch", $_POST['batch'], time() + 31536000);
    )
    else if(!isset($_POST['remember'])) {
        if(isset($_COOKIE['batch'])) {
            $past = time() - 31536000;
            setcookie(batch, '', $past);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Wrong brackets for `if` condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the following line:

```
if(isset($_POST['remember']))
```

You've used normal brackets instead of curly brackets for your statement. It should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['remember'])) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['login1']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['remember']))
            setcookie("batch", $_POST['batch'], time() + 31536000);
        elseif(!isset($_POST['remember'])) {
            if(isset($_COOKIE['batch'])) {
                $past = time() - 31536000;
                setcookie(batch, '', $past);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login1']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['remember']))
        {
            setcookie("batch", $_POST['batch'], time() + 31536000);
        }
        else if(!isset($_POST['remember']))
        {
            if(isset($_COOKIE['batch'])) 
            {
                $past = time() - 31536000;
                setcookie(batch, '', $past);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```